# Delete TFS branch without downloading it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, branch

I am trying to delete a branch that has not been downloaded into my workspace via following command.

`tf delete /lock:checkout /recursive $/TfsServerName/TfsFolder/Branch`

I get following error message:

`No matching items found in $/TfsServerName/TfsFolder/Branch in your workspace.`

Is there a way to delete a TFS branch without actually downloading it?

Comment: Are you trying to delete all the files in a branch, or are you trying to remove the branch entirely?

Comment: I am trying to remove the entire branch.

Comment: If you have folder names with spaces you need to add `" "`. i.e. `"$/Tfs Server Name/Tfs Folder/My Branch"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can do a non-recurisve get of only the folder with the "tf get" command. I am not aware that you can delete it when you don't have a local copy of the folder.

Comment: [link]http://blog.travisgosselin.com/tfs-deleting-folders-without-getting-latest-version/

Lets you get the folders for all branches in a certain path, so you can delete multiple at once

Answer (score 27):

Make sure the folder above the branch is mapped to the filesystem, then:

1. Open up Visual Studio's "Developer Command Prompt"
2. `cd` (change directory) into the folder above the branch
3. and run the following:

---

```
tf get .
tf delete /recursive branch-folder
tf checkin
```

This will do a non-recursive get, mark the whole branch/folder for deletion, then prompt you to enter a message and check in the change.

Should work with VS2012-2015 & TFS 2010 to current. Also tested with Visual Studio Team Services hosted TFS (as of 25th Feb 2016)

---

With VS2012 / TFS server 2010, the `delete` command needs `/recursive`

Comment: With VS2012 / TFS server 2010, the delete command needs `/recursive`.

Comment: This is the best answer. Easy, fast and without hacks.  It enabled all the branches that I have deleted locally on my machine in one command (tf get .) and I could then start deleting the branches. Thanks Tim.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with VS2017, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the Source Control Explorer you can get the latest version of a branch then cancel it as soon as it starts downloading. That will un-ghost the branch allowing you to delete it through the interface. You'll also have to delete the few files that were downloaded to your local work space. It's a total hack but it's really quick and easy.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from downloading 2+ GB just to subsequently delete it! This "hack" is a good work-around for a bad TFS implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Source Control Explorer`, if you simply **map the branch to a local path** and hit OK, it will enable the "delete dropdown".