# Delete Branch and create a new from existing branch

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops

I'm looking to delete the SBX branch and create a new branch called SBX utilizing the existing DEV branch, so essentially overwriting SBX with DEV. If there is a way to just over-write a branch with another in one swoop, I'd be interested in that as well. Screenshot for reference
[image: Branches]

I'm wanting to do this with Powershell/API's. I looked at the following URL [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) but can't figure out how to use these API's.

For example I ran the following to get list of my branches

```
https://dev.azure.com/jaredsplayground/JaredsPlayground/_apis/git/repositories/Jared/refs?api-version=6.0
```

but get back the following back:

Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong and how to overwrite SBX with DEV?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried to overwrite. But we can create new branch based on the DEV branch.

Please make sure you have created a PAT with the correct scopes selected. See [Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) for details.

Generally, we can create branch based on the existing branches or commits, so the `newObjectId` actually is the `ObjectID` of the specific branch or the commit ID.

We can get the `ObjectID` of the existing branches with the following REST API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_ID}/refs?api-version=5.1
```

And get the commits with this REST API :

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_ID}/commits?api-version=5.1
```

Then we can create a new branch with the specific `ObjectID` or `CommitID`:

Below PowerShell script for your reference to create a new branch:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
   [string]$project = "projectname",
   [string]$repoid = "62c8ce54-a7bb-4e08-8ed7-40b27831bd8b",
   [string]$Newbranch_name = "Test",
   [string]$newObjectId= "Existing Branch objectID or the commit ID ",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT-Here"
)
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
    [ { "name": "refs/heads/$Newbranch_name",
        "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
        "newObjectId": "$newObjectId" } ]
"@
 return $value
}
$json = CreateJsonBody
# Create new Branch 
$NewBranch = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoid/refs?api-version=5.1" 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $NewBranch -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

**UPDATE:**

DevOps doesn't have the equal REST API on a TFVC repo. See [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). You can try using the related [TFVC commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops), [tf branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops) for your reference.

You can also try to use the Git repo instead of the TFVC repo. Just import the TFVC repo to a new Git repo. See [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: This is for a TFVC repot NOT a GIT repot. How can I accomplish this on a TFVC repo? different API's, etc. Thank you

Comment: @jssteele89 DevOps doesn't have the equal REST API on a TFVC repo. See [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). You can try using the related [TFVC commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops), [tf branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use the 'TF' commands on a pipeline? for example to delete a branch and then create a new one based off an existing branch?

Comment: @jssteele89 Actually, I don't think we can achieve that smoothly with the TF tool in pipeline, firstly you need to install the tool on your agent machine, then need a local copy of the branch, then delete it and check in the changes. Reference this thread to delete the branch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991755/delete-tfs-branch-without-downloading-it.  To create a branch, you can reference [Examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops#examples), but seems no sample based on an existing branchl.